# NSOutlineView NSTableRowView Loses Apparent Selection After Editing

Tags: macos, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have a view-based outline view (OSX 10.7).  Clicking on an item selects it, as usual.  Double clicking allows editing of the textfield it contains.  However, when I'm done editing the textField, the row's highlight disappears.  The outlineView still thinks the row is selected, and sending that row a drawSelectionInRect message doesn't change its appearance.  Telling the outlineView to again select the row also doesn't change its appearance.  Only by again clicking on the row can I get the highlight to reappear.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault.  I'm observing changes to the managedObjectContext, and was reloading the entire tree when individual items changed:  by correcting this to reload only the affected item, things work as they should.